# How to pass an array as a test parameter in JUnit Parameterized testing?

Tags: java, selenium, junit

I have an array of strings and for each string in the array I want to verify that it is displayed on a webpage and then open that link. I can't figure out how to make my test a parameterized one. An help would me much appreciated, thanks

```
package testCases;

import junitparams.JUnitParamsRunner;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import pageObjects.HomePage;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

/**
 * Created by blah on 12/17/2015.
 */

@RunWith(value = JUnitParamsRunner.class)
public class ******
{

    // Create Page Objects
    HomePage hp;
    WebDriver driver;

    ArrayList<String> tableData = new ArrayList<String>();



//    @Test
//    @Parameters({something})
//

//    public void test_add(String asdas) {
//        hp.checkLink(asdas);
//    }


    @Before
    public void setup()
    {
        // Configure Chrome Options
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
       options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        // Initialize Page Objects
        hp = PageFactory.initElements(driver, HomePage.class);
    }



    // Pre Reqs
    @Test
    public void P1()
    {
        driver.get("the website I go to");
        tableData= hp.readSystemTableData();
        hp.checkLinks(tableData);
       // hp.getTitle();
        tearDown();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown()
    {
        driver.quit();
    }
}


java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at junitparams.internal.InvokeParameterisedMethod.evaluate(InvokeParameterisedMethod.java:211)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at junitparams.internal.ParameterisedTestMethodRunner.runMethodInvoker(ParameterisedTestMethodRunner.java:47)
    at junitparams.internal.ParameterisedTestMethodRunner.runTestMethod(ParameterisedTestMethodRunner.java:40)
    at junitparams.internal.ParameterisedTestClassRunner.runParameterisedTest(ParameterisedTestClassRunner.java:147)
    at junitparams.JUnitParamsRunner.runChild(JUnitParamsRunner.java:414)
    at junitparams.JUnitParamsRunner.runChild(JUnitParamsRunner.java:385)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:78)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:212)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is - there's plenty of documentation on how to use parameterised JUnit tests; where are you stuck?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth  tried following the documentation but I could not get it working. Maybe I don't undertsnad it corrcetly, if I run my test as it is I get an error saying mismatch or parameters( I added error log to question)

Comment: You don't define any `@Parameters`, how is that supposed to work?

Comment: @KirilS. I did try this, I just commented out my code which wasn't working before posting. I did define parameters and that is when I got my error, I was stuck, needed guidance so I posted here

Comment: My point is, to use `JUnitParamsRunner.class` you need to have `@Parameters` on a test, i.e.:  
  
    `@Test @Parameters    public void P1()`

Answer (score 0):

You can do parameterized test case as below :

```
@RunWith(JUnitParamsRunner.class)

public class ****

{
    // ..... code .....

    public static final Object[] getTableData()
    {

        return new Object[][] {{data1},{data2},{data3}};

    }

    @Test
    @Parameters(method = "getTableData")

    public void p1(String tblData)
    {

        //.....code.....

        hp.checkLinks(tblData);

        //.....code.....

    }
    // .... code .....
}
```

Try this way. it may work. this is the another way of doing.